# C# Web API Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# Web API project which has a Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and the following method to get a Product by it's Id:

```
public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return item;
}
```

Say I now have 10 different C# projects (i.e. not in the same solution, and a mixture of Windows Forms, Console, MVC etc) that all want to call this method and get a Product. I want to reduce the need for all 10 separate projects to have to have a class file for a Product object which is just duplicating the same structure, and also avoid using a class library DLL that is added to each project, is this possible somehow?

I know when I've previously used web services in .NET (these were the original services that created a WSDL file, and also WCF services), Visual Studio (I think) automatically created these classes behind the scenes based on the WSDL information which meant you could just consume a service and not have to worry about hand crafting each object yourself.

Is this possible to do in a Web API environment?

Comment: Create a .NET Standard class library with only these classes inside and use it in every project where you need it.

Comment: You can either generate metadata (Swagger, WADL, ...) and generate client classes from that metadata, or move your models to a class library and package that up (preferably with a client class, for example using RestSharp). Plenty of duplicates describe this.

Comment: I'd like to avoid a class library as that's what we are moving away from. I'll have a look into Swagger, thanks.

Comment: If you have a WebApi project, then that GetProduct method is presumably exposed through a route in a controller. Then all these other projects can use a web request to post and retrieve data to/from the urls of the WebApi project. So yes, that's perfectly feasible. Instead of making a direct all to the GetProduct function via a shared class library project, you're now abstracting that into a RESTful API.